# C#/Unity3D - Unable to Stitch together body parts for a 3D model

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to stitch together a body of a 3D model with all limbs split into one whole model. Like combine Head,Torso,Arms,Legs into one whole body.

Here is the code I use to generate a whole body:

```
public class Stitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void AddEquipmentToRig(GameObject equipmentGameObject, GameObject targetObject)
    {
        SkinnedMeshRenderer mainSkinnedMeshRenderer = targetObject.GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        SkinnedMeshRenderer[] equipmentSkinnedMeshRenderers = equipmentGameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
   
        for (var i = 0; i < equipmentSkinnedMeshRenderers.Length; i++) {
            SkinnedMeshRenderer equipmentSkinnedMeshRenderer = equipmentSkinnedMeshRenderers[i];

            equipmentSkinnedMeshRenderer.rootBone = mainSkinnedMeshRenderer.rootBone;
            equipmentSkinnedMeshRenderer.bones = mainSkinnedMeshRenderer.bones;
        }
        equipmentGameObject.transform.SetParent(targetObject.transform);
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the procedure:

```
private void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Trying to build a Race!");
    RaceModelSO firstRace = _races[0];
    GameObject stiches = Instantiate(firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots()[0].mesh, new Vector3(773,0.83F,778), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    stiches.name = "HumanMale";
    for (int i = 0; i < firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots().Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            GameObject bodyPart = Instantiate(firstRace.GetRaceBodySlots()[i].mesh) as GameObject;
            _stitcher.AddEquipmentToRig(bodyPart, stiches);
        }
    }
}
```

Now take a look at the result:

[image]

It creates all the limbs but they seems not to be stitched together. On top of that it creates copies of the `BaseRig` instead of attaching all the added meshes in runtime into the one `BaseRig`. So in final the stitching seems not to work.

Can you please tell why and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't observe any code here that attempts to stitch two meshes together into one combined model. Have you left something out, or have I misunderstood your aim?

Comment: @DMGregory The code, which he got [from the Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/stitch-multiple-body-parts-into-one-character.16485/page-3), appears to have been intended to assign the bones from a complete body to equipment attached to the body (presumably things like weapons and armor).

Comment: @Kevin you are right sir. Any suggestion how to achieve that ?

Comment: @VenelinVasilev It's already been [closed as a dupe on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68375103/950488), but in the future please note that [cross posting is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/228147) - that is you should not post the same question on different Stack Exchange sites.  Ask the question on the site you think will give you the best answer with respect to the problem.

Comment: @VenelinVasilev What are you trying to achieve? Attach equipment to the bones of a complete character mesh, combine separate body parts into one mesh, or join multiple bones into one skeleton?

Comment: @Kevin I have 1 rig and all limbs split into separate meshes. I would like to combine them in runtime all using the rig they are intended to use.